# open sharepoint pages from everywhere except on the server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access-denied, access

i installed SharePoint from 2003 and 2007 and 2010  in many cases. and usually anything is ok.

but several times i cant open sites with explorer

today test it and understand that only server cant access it self and anothers can do anything

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized sharepoint

internet explorer after check credentials request for enter them again.

and i mixed up

please help me

//EDIT

i configure and check firewall and etc.

i check host file in system32 / drivers / etc /

but no one solve my problem

Comment: You probably did, but since you mention you can't access it from the server, have you disabled the IIS loopback check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to disable the loopback check on the server itself:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Method 2

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, instead add some of the main steps to take and use the link merely as a source of more information

Comment: this is amazing that my server name and central admin is open by server original name : like : win-el04insm64e , but i cant open it by alias name , another host header ...